# Java: Manual Binary Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, preorder

We have an assignment in my data structures class where we have to manually build a binary tree with 7 nodes total, and display the data in each node in a preorder traversal. The root node has 2 children, and each of those 2 children has 2 children. I've got up to the point of creating the whole left side down to the end of the first tree, but am stuck at this point with a Null Pointer Exception once I create the first Right Child. I've searched other projects similar to this and I still can't seem to find out what the problem with this code is. I've found code that creates the tree's much better than we've been assigned to do, but we are limited in class to manually creating the left and right children. Any outside perspective to help out what is probably a simple program to create would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node a = new Node(1);
    Node b = new Node(2);
    Node c = new Node(3);
    Node d = new Node(4);
    Node e = new Node(5);
    Node f = new Node(6);
    Node g = new Node(7);
    BinaryTree t = new BinaryTree(a);

    t.addleft(a);
    t.addleft(b);
    t.addleft(c);
    t.addParent();
    t.addRight(d);
    t.addParent();
    //t.addParent();
    //t.addRight(e);
    //t.addleft(f);
    //t.addParent();
    //t.addRight(g);


    //System.out.println(n.getData());          

    t.preOrder(t.root);
}
```

}

```
public class BinaryTree {
Node root;
Node current;

public BinaryTree(Node n){
    root = n;
    n.setParent(current);
    current = n;
}

public void addleft(Node n){    
    current.setLeft(n);
    current = n;        
}

public void addRight(Node n){   
    current.setRight(n);
    current = n;        
}

public void addParent(){
    current = current.getParent();
}

public void preOrder(Node n){
    if(n != null){
        System.out.println(n.getData());
        preOrder(n.leftChild);
        preOrder(n.rightChild);
        return;
    }
    return;

}
```

}

```
public class Node {
Node parent;
Node rightChild;
Node leftChild;
int data;

public Node(int i) {
    data = i;
    parent = null;
    rightChild = null;
    leftChild = null;
}

public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Node aParent) {
    parent = aParent;
}

public Node getLeft() {
    return leftChild;
}

public void setLeft(Node left) {
    leftChild = left;
}

public void setRight(Node right) {
    rightChild = right;
}

public Node getRight() {
    return rightChild;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because when you create the Binary Tree with Node a as your root, c does not have a parent.

When you call

```
t.addParent();
t.addRight(d);
```

the first line sets current to null, then the second line attempts to use the null value.

Comment: I've stared at this for the past hour and am still confused as to where the parent variable is losing it's value. Is it because of the "current = n;" line in the BinaryTree class, addLeft and addRight methods?

Comment: Taking it step by step. When a Node is created, it has no parent (parent = null;). All nodes are created this way. You create a BinaryTree with Node a (value 1, parent = null). Then you call addLeft 3 times. Each time, the value of current is set to the Node you passed in. After t.addleft(c), the value of current is a Node that has no parent. When you call t.addParent();, it calls sets current to the value of currents parent, which is null (no Node has a parent yet).Then, when you call t.addRight(d), you call current.setRight(n), which is null.setRight(n), which is your null pointer exception.

Comment: Wow, I just added my "n.setParent(current);" to each the addLeft and addRight method and it seems to have worked. Seriously, I can't thank you enough for walking me through all of this! So would you have put the set parent code in with each adding method (assuming you were tasked to build the project this way)?

Comment: Yeah. When you add a Node, you know the parent of that Node, and so you should just set it then. ie. After each addition of a node, your tree should have the complete set of information necessary for traversing it. By the way - if this answer solved your issue, click on the tick to accept it :)

Comment: Makes sense after thinking about it in hindsight. Thanks again! Huge help